# Using WCF Extensibility at Client Side

Tags: wcf

I am using a web application as a client to invoke WCF methods using proxy.

For each request being made by client object, I need to populate few properties (declared inside request class)
Is it possible to hook a method, just before making the actual web service call.

I can't modify service code right now, Can WCF extensibility points could be leveraged in this case?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: that is possible. To get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733848.aspx

Comment: Need more information about the data. Are "IP address and computer name fields" used as an address for the WCF proxy to make the call or are these fileds in a DataContract that all the methods are passing to the service? Give as much detail as you can.

Comment: @ErnieL yes these are properties defined inside classes. Updated the question to remove ambiguity.

Comment: That's clear now, but Carlos beat to the answer. Do what he said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the properties of the method *parameters*, you can use an `IParameterInspector` to do that, since at that point you'll get an array with all parameters to be sent to the server.

If you need to change other parts of the request (such as transport or SOAP headers), an `IClientMessageInspector` may be the best way to go.

For more information on many extensibility points at the client side, you can check the blog series at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx.

Comment: Can you please help on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682535/define-inside-to-web-config