# Move C# WCF Extensibility code to Configuration File

Tags: wcf

Following code adds ParameterInspector to the endpoint.

```
ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>("BasicHttpBinding_ITest");
OperationProfilerManager clientProfilerManager = new OperationProfilerManager();
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new OperationProfilerEndpointBehavior(clientProfilerManager));
ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

As a good practice, We are attempting to move all this code to Web.config. So that merely creating factory like this

```
ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>("BasicHttpBinding_ITest");
```

or this -

```
ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>();
```

should fetch the extension elements from configuration. With following configurations, **BeforeCall** or **AfterCall** methods of **IParameterInspector** is not being triggered. Can you please point out our mistake in following Web.config -

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITest" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://n1:8000/Service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITest" contract="ServiceReference1.ITest"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ITest" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="todo">                
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="OperationProfilerEndpointBehavior" type="SelfHostedServiceClient.OperationProfilerEndpointBehavior, SelfHostedServiceClient"/>
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thank you for your help.

Reference:  [Carlos blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/26/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector.aspx)

**EDIT: Resolution**

Based on Carlos answer, I took following steps to resolve the issue.

Step 1. Created OperationProfilerBehaviorElement class derived from BehaviorExtensionElement. This class is responsible for instantiating the class implementing **IEndpointBehavior**

```
class OperationProfilerBehaviorElement : BehaviorExtensionElement  {
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get {
            return typeof(OperationProfilerEndpointBehavior);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        OperationProfilerManager clientProfilerManager = new OperationProfilerManager();
        return new OperationProfilerEndpointBehavior(clientProfilerManager);
    } }
```

Step 2. This class had to be declared in Web.config as below,

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="OperationProfilerBehavior" type="SelfHostedServiceClient.OperationProfilerBehaviorElement, SelfHostedServiceClient"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Step 3. Added **Endpoint behavior** as below,

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="**InspectParameters**">
      <OperationProfilerBehavior/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Step 4. Set **behaviorConfiguration** attribute of the endpoint equal to InspectParameters as below,

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/Service" behaviorConfiguration="InspectParameters"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITest"
    contract="ServiceReference1.ITest" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITest" />
```

Now I was able to initialize factory in a single C# line and **parameter inspector** was added by default from Web.config

> ChannelFactory factory = new ChannelFactory("BasicHttpBinding_ITest");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `OperationProfilerEndpointBehavior` which is referenced in the `<extensions> / <behaviorExtensions>` section of the config should not be a class implementing `IEndpointBehavior` - it should be a type which inherits from `BehaviorElementExtension`, and that class is the one which should create the behavior.

See more information about behavior extensions at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions.aspx.

Comment: Hi Carlos, Can you please help on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224182/restrict-access-to-a-datamember-on-few-endpoints