# Modify WCF Service Request before it is validated against Service Contract

Tags: wcf

I have been trying to intercept the request just before making service call.

[Using WCF Extensibility at Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642093/using-wcf-extensibility-at-client-side)

The idea behind this was to add certain properties inside the request so that when request is validated against ServiceContract Schema, request must appear valid.

I used IParameterInspector and BehaviorExtension as suggested here -

[Move C# WCF Extensibility code to Configuration File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682535/move-c-sharp-wcf-extensibility-code-to-configuration-file)

However it seems serivce request is being validated at client side, even before call reaches **IParameterInspecter** `public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)` method. where I intended to add the properties.

But just at the time of making service call, getting following error -

> The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[SomeService.IServiceContract],
>   cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Where should I intercept the service call, to add properties to the request.

Have to make sure to do this before request is validated against schema at the clientside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faulted channels usually results from a unexpected exception (not explicitly defined in the contract) thrown by the service in response to a client request.
If it happens before the `BeforeCall` it can come from different causes.

The first one that comes to mind is that you incorrectly plugged your `IParameterInspecter` and it doesn't go through it, you should start by testing if it is correctly plugged with a simplified scenario.

If not, it might come from an authentication request being generated before the service method call as defined by `establishSecurityContext="true"` of the message security, the authentication request being rejected with an unexpected exception, it faults the channel and you can't use it anymore.

There isn't enough information for me to think about other possibles causes.
You should start by checking those and come back with additional code and/or configuration samples for further investigation.